# MySQLi Prepared statement query won't run

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was trying to make an API of post method that and take one value from the database from my post method.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $response = array();
    //get data
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $key_check = $_POST['key_check'];
    require_once('Connection.php');

    $check_key = "SELECT key_check FROM testing1 WHERE username =? AND password =?";
    $insert_key= "UPDATE testing1 SET key_check =? WHERE username =? AND password = ?";
    // $insert_key = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (username, password, key_check) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    
    if ($result_p = mysqli_prepare($connection,$check_key)){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result_p,"ss",$username,$password);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($result_p);

        $row = $result_p ->get_result();


        
        while ($row1 = $row -> fetch_assoc()){
            if(isset($row1["key_check"])){
                if($result_p2 = mysqli_prepare($connection,$insert_key)){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result_p2,"sss",$username,$password,$key_check);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($result_p2);
                mysqli_stmt_close($result_p2);
               }         
            }else{
                //do something
            }
        }  
    }
    else{
    //do something
    }'''
```

As you can see in the code above, The code will take the key_check value from the first query and then then based on the result if it's null or not, the program will run the second query to add the data from the from the post method. I already checked that the value is null but for some reason the second query did not want to run, is there any thing that I could do or does my logic is wrong in the first place?

Comment: Because when key_check is null, you are calling isset on it and it returns false. Did you mean !isset()?

Comment: You don't need to use two queries. Just `UPDATE testing1 SET key_check =? WHERE username =? AND password = ? AND key_check IS NULL`